# Openproject - Apache + Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger, openproject

I'm trying to get the open project app to start on boot. For this reason I followed this guide https://community.openproject.org/topics/576?board_id=9 (and tried a couple of others aswell) to install apache + passenger.

My problem is that the app wont start on apache restart (with sudo service apache2 restart) but it will start with the command 'passenger start'.
My virtual host file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName domain.com
  # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!

  DocumentRoot /home/openproject/openproject/public
  <Directory /home/openproject/openproject/public>
     # This relaxes Apache security settings

    AllowOverride all
     # MultiViews must be turned off.
     Options -MultiViews
     # Uncomment this if you're on Apache >= 2.4:
     #Require all granted
  </Directory>
```

Passenger log:

```
[ 2014-11-21 13:39:20.5600 3559/7f539284f740 apache2/Hooks.cpp:1303 ]: Initializing Phusion Passenger...
[ 2014-11-21 13:39:20.5632 3562/7fec64602740 agents/Base.cpp:1591 ]: Random seed: 1416573560
[ 2014-11-21 13:39:20.5632 3562/7fec64602740 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:698 ]: Starting Watchdog...
[ 2014-11-21 13:39:20.5633 3562/7fec64602740 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:538 ]: Options: { 'analytics_log_user' => 'nobody', 'default_group' => 'nogroup', 'default_python' => 'python', 'default_ruby' => '/home/openproject/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/wrappers/ruby', 'default_user' => 'nobody', 'log_level' => '3', 'max_pool_size' => '6', 'passenger_root' => '/home/openproject/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.53', 'passenger_version' => '4.0.53', 'pool_idle_time' => '300', 'temp_dir' => '/tmp', 'union_station_gateway_address' => 'gateway.unionstationapp.com', 'union_station_gateway_port' => '443', 'user_switching' => 'true', 'web_server_passenger_version' => '4.0.53', 'web_server_pid' => '3559', 'web_server_type' => 'apache', 'web_server_worker_gid' => '33', 'web_server_worker_uid' => '33' }
[ 2014-11-21 13:39:20.5703 3566/7fc738409740 agents/Base.cpp:1591 ]: Random seed: 1416573560
[ 2014-11-21 13:39:20.5703 3566/7fc738409740 agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:643 ]: Starting PassengerHelperAgent...
[ 2014-11-21 13:39:20.5749 3566/7fc738409740 agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:650 ]: PassengerHelperAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.3559/generation-0/request
[ 2014-11-21 13:39:20.5837 3576/7ffac78f3780 agents/Base.cpp:1591 ]: Random seed: 1416573560
[ 2014-11-21 13:39:20.5848 3576/7ffac78f3780 agents/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp:333 ]: Starting PassengerLoggingAgent...
[ 2014-11-21 13:39:20.5856 3576/7ffac78f3780 agents/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp:321 ]: PassengerLoggingAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.3559/generation-0/logging
[ 2014-11-21 13:39:20.5892 3562/7fec64602740 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:728 ]: All Phusion Passenger agents started!
[ 2014-11-21 13:39:20.9005 2132/7f27ef24a780 agents/LoggingAgent/LoggingServer.h:752 ]: Flushing all sinks
[ 2014-11-21 13:39:22.0002 2123/7f79effba700 Pool2/Pool.h:837 ]: Analytics collection time...
[ 2014-11-21 13:39:23.0347 2123/7f79effba700 Pool2/Pool.h:943 ]: Analytics collection done; next analytics collection in 4.965 sec
[ 2014-11-21 13:39:23.5331 3542/7f476c0e5700 Pool2/Pool.h:837 ]: Analytics collection time...
[ 2014-11-21 13:39:23.5336 3542/7f476c0e5700 Pool2/Pool.h:943 ]: Analytics collection done; next analytics collection in 4.466 sec
[ 2014-11-21 13:39:23.5755 3566/7fc7383f6700 Pool2/Pool.h:837 ]: Analytics collection time...
[ 2014-11-21 13:39:23.5759 3566/7fc7383f6700 Pool2/Pool.h:943 ]: Analytics collection done; next analytics collection in 4.424 sec
[ 2014-11-21 13:39:24.5180 2132/7f27ef24a780 agents/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp:344 ]: Logging agent exiting with code 0.
[ 2014-11-21 13:39:24.5197 2123/7f79effcd740 agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:606 ]: It's now 5 seconds after all clients have disconnected. Proceeding with graceful exit.
[ 2014-11-21 13:39:24.5197 2123/7f79effcd740 agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:507 ]: Shutting down helper agent...
[ 2014-11-21 13:39:24.5203 2123/7f79effcd740 agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:514 ]: Destroying application pool...
[ 2014-11-21 13:39:24.5208 2123/7f79effcd740 agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:543 ]: All threads have been shut down.
[ 2014-11-21 13:39:24.5211 2123/7f79effcd740 agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:660 ]: Helper agent exiting with code 0.
[ 2014-11-21 13:39:24.5323 3532/7fc0b839d740 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:388 ]: All Phusion Passenger agent processes have exited. Forcing all subprocesses to shut down.
[ 2014-11-21 13:39:24.5324 3532/7fc0b839d740 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:390 ]: Sending SIGTERM
[ 2014-11-21 13:39:25.5326 3532/7fc0b839d740 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:395 ]: Sending SIGKILL
[ 2014-11-21 13:39:25.5341 3542/7f476c0a4700 Pool2/Pool.h:684 ]: Garbage collection time...
[ 2014-11-21 13:39:25.5342 3542/7f476c0a4700 Pool2/Pool.h:733 ]: Garbage collection done; next garbage collect in 300.000 sec
[ 2014-11-21 13:39:25.5404 3547/7fceb896a780 agents/LoggingAgent/LoggingServer.h:752 ]: Flushing all sinks
[ 2014-11-21 13:39:25.5416 3547/7fceb896a780 agents/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp:344 ]: Logging agent exiting with code 0.
[ 2014-11-21 13:39:25.5444 3542/7f476c0f8740 agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:606 ]: It's now 5 seconds after all clients have disconnected. Proceeding with graceful exit.
```

It seems to start passenger and then simply dieing?

I ran out of ideas what to do so any help is apreciated

Comment: Seems to be a logging error. Does your project have a log/ folder on it? Does it have access permission?

Comment: All of the files have openproject as owner (rvm is installed on him). I have checked the log folder and put chmod 777 on the folder and files inside but it did not help.

Comment: So it works as long as you don't restart apache?

Comment: It works if I start it with the command passenger start yes and stops working when I do sudo service apache2 restart.
So I'd say yes.